# React: Highlight text between two indexes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-places-api

So for every prediction the google places autocomplete API also returns matched substrings for each one.

Input: San 68

Prediction: San Francisco 68

Matched substrings: `[{ offset: 0, length: 3 }, { offset: 15, length: 2 }]`

Expectation: **San** Francisco **68**

My goal is to highlight parts of the prediction using the matched substrings. Now there is a few challenges. I could use the `replace` function and replace every substring with `<b>str</b>`, but it returns a string which means unless I use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` this method doesn't work.

I also don't think there is a way to replace multiple substrings. I tried to use the `reduce` function but after the first loop it wouldn't really work because the indexes would be wrong.

```
const highlight = (text, matched_substrings) => {
  return matched_substrings.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return acc.replace(
      acc.substring(cur.offset, cur.length),
      (str) => `<b>${str}</b>`
    )
  }, text)
}
```

So is there a way to do this? I think React makes this more complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably not best solution, but definitely working one :)
Prerequisite is, that matched_substrigs array has to be sorted, by offsets

```
export const highlightText = (text, matched_substring, start, end) => {
    const highlightTextStart = matched_substring.offset;
    const highlightTextEnd = highlightTextStart + matched_substring.length;

    // The part before matched text
    const beforeText = text.slice(start, highlightTextStart);

    // Matched text
    const highlightedText = text.slice(highlightTextStart, highlightTextEnd);

    // Part after matched text
    // Till the end of text, or till next matched text
    const afterText = text.slice(highlightTextEnd, end || text.length);

    // Return in array of JSX elements
    return [beforeText, <strong>{highlightedText}</strong>, afterText];
};

export const highlight = (text, matched_substrings) => {
    const returnText = [];

    // Just iterate through all matches
    for (let i = 0; i < matched_substrings.length; i++) {
        const startOfNext = matched_substrings[i + 1]?.offset;
        if (i === 0) { // If its first match, we start from first character => start at index 0
            returnText.push(highlightText(text, matched_substrings[i], 0, startOfNext))
        } else { // If its not first match, we start from match.offset 
            returnText.push(highlightText(text, matched_substrings[i], matched_substrings[i].offset, startOfNext))
        }
    }

    return returnText.map((text, i) => <React.Fragment key={i}>{text}</React.Fragment>)
};
```

Comment: Could you explain the structure of `matched_substrings`, please? And what does represent the offset?

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution if you don't mind using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

```
const Highlight = ({ text, substrings }) => {
  const html = substrings.reduce((acc, cur, idx) => {
    return acc.replace(
      new RegExp(
        '(?<=^.{' + (cur.offset + idx * 17) + '})(.{' + cur.length + '})',
      ),
      (str) => `<strong>${str}</strong>`,
    )
  }, text)
  return <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
}
```

use it like this

```
<Highlight text={...} substrings={...} />
```